# how to save the new number when using the modulus operator?

Tags: java

I am writing a program that takes a number/2 and then prints the remainder and then continues until the number is 0.

Example 13/2 remainder = 1 6/2 remainder = 0 3/2 remainder = 1 1/2 remainder = 1

Here is what I wrote. I have tried some different code, but it just resulted in an infinite loop. this seems to compile but it just returns the original number entered.

```
public class BinaryDigits
{
    int number;
    int quotient;
    int remainder;

    public BinaryDigits(int input)
    {   
        number = input;
    }


    public int getDigits()
    {
        while (quotient > 0)
        {
            quotient = number / 2;
            remainder = number % 2;
            System.out.println(remainder);
        }
        return number;
    }


}
```

Comment: You want to divide number by 2, and print the remainder.

Comment: Are you sure number doesn't change? Or does it just get to 1 and `1%2` is always 1 so it gets stuck here?

Answer (score 1):

**problem:**

```
while (quotient > 0)
```

It will always be `number / 2` and will never decrease or increase thus resulting to infinite loop.

**solution:**

```
int number = 13;
    int remainder;
    while (number != 0)
    {
        remainder = number % 2;
        System.out.println(remainder);
        number = number / 2;
    }
```

You need to calculate the divided `number` and assign it again to the `number` variable so by the time it hits 0 it will then break the while loop.

**result:**

```
1
0
1
1
```

Comment: Thanks I must have posted it just before you

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. thanks

```
public class BinaryDigits
{
    int number;
    int quotient;
    int remainder;

    public BinaryDigits(int input)
    {   
        number = input;
    }


    public int getDigits()
    {
        while (number > 0)
        {
            remainder = number % 2;
            System.out.println(remainder);
            number = number / 2;
        }
        return number;
    }


}
```